# String value from mongoose document weird behaviour adding in a variable

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, mongoose, bson

I have a mongo document called `New` which has a sub document called `hashtags` which has th value `name` which is a `string`. I am trying to add all the hashtags belongs to a new in a variable but is adding extra characters (seems that the `name` string value is not well decoded from the `bson` or something like that).

**New document**:

```
var newSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    hashtags: [{
        type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Hashtag'
    }]
});
```

**Hashtag document**:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema

    var hashtagSchema = new Schema({
        color:  {
            type: String,
            default: '#000000'
        },
        name:  {
            type: String
        }
    });
    var hashtag = mongoose.model('Hashtag', hashtagSchema )

    module.exports = hashtag
```

**Snniped testing code**:

```
    docs.forEach(noticia => {
        if(noticia.hashtags.length > 0){
            for(i in noticia.hashtags){
                if(noticia.hashtags[i] && noticia.hashtags[i].name){
                    text +=  '#' + noticia.hashtags[i].name.replace(/\s/g,'') + ' '
                }
            }
        }
    })
console.log(text)
```

**Console output**:

`#Lula #toBSON #_cast #_markModified #_registerAtomic #$__getAtomics #hasAtomics #_mapCast #push #nonAtomicPush #$pop #pop #$shift #shift #pull #splice #unshift #sort #addToSet #set #toObject #inspect #indexOf #pull`

I have tried to apply `noticia.hashtags[i].name.replace(/\s/g,'').toString()` :

```
    docs.forEach(noticia => {
        if(noticia.hashtags.length > 0){
            for(i in noticia.hashtags){
                if(noticia.hashtags[i] && noticia.hashtags[i].name){
                    text +=  noticia.hashtags[i].name.toString() + ' '
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

**Console output**
`LulatoBSON_cast_markModified_registerAtomic$__getAtomicshasAtomics_mapCastpushnonAtomicPush$poppop$shiftshiftpullspliceunshiftsortaddToSetsettoObjectinspectindexOfpull`

How I have to decode this string value?

Comment: Can you give an example of the special characters you are seeing? In the second example you don't seem to be adding the '#'

Comment: In the second example I have removed the #. I don't use any other special character. In the example, the `hashtags[0].name = 'Lula'`and `hashtags.length == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **for...in** statement iterates over all non-Symbol, enumerable properties of an object.

```
var string1 = "";
var object1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

for (var property1 in object1) {
  string1 += object1[property1];
}

console.log(string1);
// expected output: "123"
```

You are iterating over the properties of *noticia.hashtags*

Comment: It works changing `for...in` for  `noticia.hashtags.forEach(hashtag => {})` . Thank you!